# Highlighting duplicate rows in Excel

Tags: excel

Under SHEET1 I have 100 rows of data spanning 15 columns.
Under SHEET2 I have 10 rows of data also spanning 15 columns.

I need to highlight the rows in SHEET1 that are already in SHEET2.

How can I do this?

Thanks All.

Comment: "SHEET1 that are already in SHEET2." - what do you consider a match? are you matching all 15 columns? or just one column?

Comment: It must match all 15 columns. Thank you for pointing that. I missed it in the question.

Comment: without using VBA, just concatenate all 15 columns in column 16th in both sheets; then do a vlookup.

Comment: is there text? or are these numbers/dates?

Comment: All these are mixed values of dates, numbers and free text.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only have a paltry 10 rows in your second sheet a very manual approach may be simplest. Just copy the ten rows below the 100 select all 15 columns and apply Remove Duplicates. Observe which of the ten (if any) go missing and Undo (or you may delete duplicates within the 100).

Then find those identified as missing within the 100 and manually highlight them.